# Retrieving REST data in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to create an app that integrates with a REST api using MVVM. I'm struggling with pulling data from an endpoint in my View Model and binding the data to my View. Here is what I have so far as a test.

View Model

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }

    private List<Schedule> schedules;
    public List<Schedule> Schedules
    {
        get
        {
            if (schedules == null)
                GetData();
            return schedules;
        }
        set
        {
            schedules = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Schedules");
        }
    }
    private string homeTeam;
    public string HomeTeam
    {
        get
        {
            return homeTeam;
        }
        set
        {
            homeTeam = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("HomeTeam");
        }
    }
    private async void GetData()
    {
        // Simulate pulling data from api
        string response;
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///DesignData/GetLive.json"));
        using (StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
            response = await sRead.ReadToEndAsync();

        // Deserialize data to class
        LiveStreamModel liveGames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LiveStreamModel>(response);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

View

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Schedules}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding HomeTeam}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Model

```
class LiveStreamModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public List<Schedule> schedule { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<Schedule> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.schedule.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
public class Schedule
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string @event { get; set; }
    public string homeTeam { get; set; }
    public int homeScore { get; set; }
    public string awayTeam { get; set; }
    public int awayScore { get; set; }
    public string startTime { get; set; }
    public int period { get; set; }
    public int isHd { get; set; }
    public int isPlaying { get; set; }
    public int isWMV { get; set; }
    public int isFlash { get; set; }
    public int isiStream { get; set; }
    public string feedType { get; set; }
    public string srcUrl { get; set; }
    public string hdUrl { get; set; }
    public string sdUrl { get; set; }
    public string trueLiveSD { get; set; }
    public string trueLiveHD { get; set; }
}
```

Normally in the past I would have called the `GetData()` method in my View's code behind and set the `ItemSource` for the ListView there. How can i get this working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the property in the view model:

```
// Deserialize data to class
LiveStreamModel liveGames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LiveStreamModel>(response);
Schedules = liveGames.schedule;
```

And make sure that you data-bind the text block in the data template to a property of the `Schedule` type (the data-binding there targets the list items, not the view model, so the `HomeTeam` property of the view model is unused):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Schedules}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding homeTeam}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

---

Btw. the getter of `Schedules` should not call `GetData` like that and expect `schedules` to be initialized. Instead, explicitely set up the field and then you may asynchronously call `GetData` to start loading the data (which then later updates the property):

```
get
{
    if (schedules == null)
    {
        schedules = new List<Schedule>();
        GetData();
    }
    return schedules;
}
```

Even better though would be to explicitely call `GetData()` somewhere else, so you *explicitely* set up the view model and don’t have an asynchronous process running somewhere in the (unmonitored) background.

Comment: Ah ok. So realistically i shouldn't need to create properties in my View Model for all the fields i have under `Schedule` in my model right?

Comment: No, you expose a list of schedules, and then databind that list to your list box. So when you then—inside your list view—want to display certain properties of a schedule, you can just access them directly. Essentially, the `Schedule` becomes a (simple) view model for a list view item.